# How do I get British Summertime offset (BST) in Java

Tags: java, timezone

In the UK, I'd like to get the current offset from UTC/GMT. Currently the offset is 1 hour, but there seems to be no way of finding this.

Code

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    logger.debug("Timezone ID is '" + timeZone.getID() + "'");
    if (timeZone.getID().equals("GMT")) {
        timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
        logger.debug("New timezone is '" + timeZone.getID() + "'");
    }
    Long eventDateMillis = Long.parseLong(eventDateValue.getKeyValue());
    int timezoneOffset = timeZone.getOffset(eventDateMillis);
    logger.debug("Offset for " + eventDateValue + "(" + eventDateMillis + ") using timezone " + timeZone.getDisplayName() + " is " + timezoneOffset);
```

returns debug output

```
Wed 2012/09/19 16:38:19.503|Debug|DataManagement|Timezone ID is 'GMT'
Wed 2012/09/19 16:38:19.503|Debug|DataManagement|New timezone is 'GMT'
Wed 2012/09/19 16:38:19.557|Debug|DataManagement|Offset for 18 Sep 2012 09:00(1347958800000) using timezone Greenwich Mean Time is 0
```

In other words, timezone 'GMT' is returning an offset of zero and I can't find how to set it to something that does return the correct offset.

If someone can provide a working code sample for JodaTime, that would do but I'd really like to avoid having to install a separate library just for what should be a one-liner.

The Java version is 7.

Comment: You say "correct offset". What would the correct offset be for GMT?

Comment: GMT/UTC should be 0, what I want is BST, which should be 1 hour's worth of ms currently: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136

Comment: Here is the output I get for the following code: `TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"); int timezoneOffset = timeZone.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()); System.out.println("Offset for timezone " + timeZone.getID() + " is " + timezoneOffset);` => `Offset for timezone Europe/London is 3600000` which is pretty much what you expect no ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In other words, timezone 'GMT' is returning an offset of zero and I can't find how to set it to something that does return the correct offset.

0 *is* the correct offset for GMT, permanently.

You want "Europe/London", which is the time zone which switches between GMT and BST.

EDIT: I hadn't originally noticed that you're *trying* to get Europe/London. It looks like the time zone database your JVM is using is basically messed up. You could either try fixing *that*, or simply use Joda Time which comes with its own copy of tzdb. Sample code:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
long offset = zone.getOffset(new Instant());
System.out.println(offset); // 3600000
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this myself.

I tried TimeZone.getTimeZone("London"); and it worked.

No I have no idea why - 'London' isn't one of the IDs TimeZone returns...

Comment: Maybe because London can be in TimeZone GMT or BST (summer time) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use timezone.getOffset( 0 ), instead of timezone.getOffset( eventDateMillis ).

This will give you the offset as of January 1st, 1970 GMT time, which in the case of Europe/London is 3600000, NOT zero due to historical issues with Wales and Northern Ireland.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

[`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) has been designed to adjust the timezone offset automatically.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(10, 20);
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        // A winter date-time
        ZonedDateTime zdtWinter = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 22), time, zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtWinter);

        // A summer date-time
        ZonedDateTime zdtSummer = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 07, 22), time, zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtSummer);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-11-22T10:20Z[Europe/London]
2021-07-22T10:20+01:00[Europe/London]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/z5CVjZ)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>. However, for any reason, if you need to convert an object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdtSummer.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This made me the trick:

```
String zone = "Europe/London";
int plusHoursGMT = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone).getRawOffset() / 3600000;
assertThat(plusHoursGMT, is(0));
```